# Passing down multiple methods within single prop React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react.js component where I want to pass down a bunch of different methods to child components from the parent component, the methods modify the state of the parent component.

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: this.props.items,
      currentItemID: 1
    };

    this.actions = this.actions.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page">
        {
          this.state.items.map(item =>
            <Item key={item._id} item={item} actions={this.actions} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

  actions() {
    return {
      insertItem: function (itemID) {
        const currentItems = this.state.items;
        const itemPosition = this.state.items.map((item) => item._id).indexOf(itemID);

        const blankItem = {
          _id: (new Date().getTime()),
          content: ''
        };

        currentItems.splice(itemPosition + 1, 0, blankItem)

        this.setState({
          items: currentItems,
          lastAddedItemID: blankItem._id
        });
      },
      setCurrentItem: function (itemID) {
        this.setState({ currentItemID: itemID });
      },
      focus: function(itemID) {
        return (itemID === this.state.currentItemID);
      }
    }
  }
```

In my child component, I am trying to use the focus method in the componentDidMount lifecyle method as shown below:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.actions().focus(this.props.item._id)) {
      this.nameInput.focus();
    }
  }
```

However, I am getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentItemID' of undefined

in the definition of the focus method, within the actions methods. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I'm getting the error or an alternative way to pass down multiple actions to child components?

Comment: I think, your main error - its that you call your actions inside the method - it will create some unexpected problems, try to pass object to the child, instead of function, and if you are using es5 - bind `this` inside the each function (Its the main error)

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to bind one of the functions to 'this' please?

Comment: .bind(this) - like in the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the context is not passed to the function, then the 'this' in the function is that of the function itself and not the component.. you can solve it that way (put the functions in the components):

```
      actions() {
         return {
            insertItem: this.insertItem.bind(this),
            setCurrentItem: this.setCurrentItem.bind(this),
            focus: this.focus.bind(this),
         }
      }
      insertItem(itemID) {
        const currentItems = this.state.items;
        const itemPosition = this.state.items.map((item) => item._id).indexOf(itemID);

        const blankItem = {
          _id: (new Date().getTime()),
          content: ''
        };

        currentItems.splice(itemPosition + 1, 0, blankItem)

        this.setState({
          items: currentItems,
          lastAddedItemID: blankItem._id
        });
      },
      setCurrentItem(itemID) {
        this.setState({ currentItemID: itemID });
      },
      focus(itemID) {
        return (itemID === this.state.currentItemID);
      }
```

but yet, the recomended way is to put the functions in the components like above and remove the actions method and do this:

```
<Item key={item._id} item={item} actions={{
            insertItem: this.insertItem.bind(this),
            setCurrentItem: this.setCurrentItem.bind(this),
            focus: this.focus.bind(this)
        }} />
```

or

```
<Item key={item._id} item={item} actions={{
            insertItem: () => this.insertItem(),
            setCurrentItem: () => this.setCurrentItem(),
            focus: () => this.focus()
        }} />
```

Comment: Actually, the item component is recursive, it has other nested items within it, then how do I pass down the different methods to the nested item within my item component? This has had me stumped for a while.

Comment: @the_archer in the child component, when you want to call the nest child one (child of child ) pass actions like that: <NestedComponent key={item._id} item={item} actions={this.props.actions} /> or you can even pass every thing(actions and other things in props) like that: <NestedComponent {...this.props} />